# Erro ao logar com React usando Fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, react

Estou construindo um software que tem uma API em Node e um client em React.

O backend está configurado e funcionando. Está logando e quando logado trás os dados que preciso.

Porém, com meu software feito em react, estou tentando logar através de Fetch:

```
static logar(usuario) {
return (
  fetch("http://localhost:5000/login", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(usuario),
    credentials: "same-origin"
  })
    .then(parseJSON)
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("request failed", error);
    })
);
```

Até aí tudo parece funcionar perfeitamente. Ele realmente loga, trás os dados do usuário etc.

Porém, ao consultar uma nova rota, ele simplesmente me retorna dizendo que não estou logado:

```
static getData() {
return (
  fetch("http://localhost:5000/teste", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    credentials: "include",
    mode: "cors"
  })
    //   .then(checkStatus)
    .then(parseJSON)
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("request failed", error);
    })
);
```

Preciso apenas de uma luz, pois não estou encontrando solução e já estou endoidando com isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acabei de encontrar o problema:

Ao fazer o post, eu estava colocando `same-origin` nas `credentials`. Alterei para `include` e resolveu o problema no software todo.

Valeu!